# How to create a common function to execute a python script in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a common python script which need to use in multiple pipeline jobs. 
What I did is create a qroovy file with common method as below.

```
def create_slaves()
{
    def cmd = 'python "-u my_script.py'
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    proc.waitfor()
}
return this
```

execution threw this exception.

```
Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods execute java.lang.String
```

So I feel like this is not the correct approach. Someone has a clue about a suitable way for execute a common python script in pipeline?

Answer (score 4):

[burnettk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731883/7311767) is on the right track but incomplete. I am not aware of an official way to run python scripts directly so try the following workaround

Store your python script in a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#directory-structure) specifically in the resources folder. (resources/yourscript.py)

Then import the file as a string and write it to a file. Eg:

```
script{
    def yourScriptAsaString = libraryResource '../resources/yourscript.py' 
    writeFile file: 'yourscript.py', text: yourScriptAsaString
    sh "python yourscript.py"
}
```

Comment: @Stephen Any reason for using the shared library and then importing instead of directly referring to the path of the file or using dir() and then just giving file name?

Comment: @merlachandra, I am not the answerer, I simply edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use a [jenkins shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) and use the `sh` step in there.

incidentally, maybe your actual use case is more nuanced than it appears from what you have shared (in which case, sure, use a shared library), but i think i'd just use the `sh` step in each Jenkinsfile, like this, and keep it simple:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        sh 'python -u my_script.py'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ran into Jenkins cautiously blocking one of the methods you called. There are a couple of ways you can get past this:

1. Install and enable https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Permissive+Script+Security+Plugin

You just have to add an argument to jenkins.xml to enable it

2. Go to Manager Jenkins -> In-process Script Approval

You'll see the method that was blocked there. Click 'Approve' and if my understanding is correct it'll never be blocked again.

You might have to iterate on this a few times until all methods your function calls get approved.